# Remove duplicate rows in Google Sheets - Remove rows nearest to the top

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet which is automatically updated with the contents of a gmail attachment each day.

I want to ensure that old duplicate rows are deleted. So the duplicate rows that are closer to the top of the sheet.

I am using the following script to delete duplicates, but unfortunately it deletes the newest rows closest to the bottom.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;});//header title to index
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['Test Name']])==-1) {
      uA.push(vA[i][hObj['Test Name']]);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer (previously didn't work)

Comment: This is great, thank you Mike. I upvoted but it says I do not have enough reputation for it to show.

Comment: you may be can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try, assuming the data starts at row 1 (headers)

```
function removeDuplicates2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = vA[0].indexOf('Test Name')
  var list = new Map()
  var rows = [];
  vA.reverse().forEach(function(e,i){
    if (list.get(e[col])){rows.push((vA.length-i))}else{list.set(e[col],(vA.length-i))}
  })
  rows.forEach(x => sh.deleteRow(x))
}
```